# Is there a way of using CakeResponse Object in unconstructed Class?

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling, cakephp-2.7

I'm currently doing a custom **ErrorHandler** for an App in ***CakePHP***.
The reason? Well, bots are always trying to find stuff in your servers and sometimes they provoke exceptions and or errors.

The idea with this **ErrorHandler** is to filter requests and respond with the appropriate headers and prevent further request damage by handling this type of requests and make it transparent for the user client *(because it might affect JavaScript for instance)*.

---

> And what better way than to use the Framework's functionality, right?
>
> The thing is that since this ErrorHandler is being used statically,
>   well, there is no constructor so nothing inherits anything, it doesn't
>   matter if you instantiate any other **CakePHP Object**.
>
> **What would be the appropriate way to use CakeResponse Object?**

---

### CakePHP's configuration:

**app/Config/bootstrap.php:**

```
App::uses('CustomErrorHandler', 'Lib');
```

**app/Config/core.php:**

```
// Error and exception handlers.
Configure::write('Error', array(
    'handler' => 'CustomErrorHandler::handleError',
    'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED,
    'trace' => true
));
Configure::write('Exception', array(
    'handler' => 'CustomErrorHandler::handleException',
    'renderer' => 'ExceptionRenderer',
    'log' => true
));
```

**app/Lib/CustomErrorHandler.php:**

```
  ... rest of class code ...

  /**
   * Named after convention: This method receives all CakePHP's
   * errors and exceptions…
   *
   * @param  array $e The exception object.
   * @return mixed    Returns the error handling or header redirection.
   */
   public static function handleException($e)
   {
       $message = (string) $e->getMessage();
       $code    = (int)    $e->getCode();
       $file    = (string) $e->getFile();
       $line    = (string) $e->getLine();

       // If it's a Blacklist resource exception it will log it and redirect to home.
       if (self::__isResourceException($message))
       {
           return self::__dismissError();
       }

       return parent::handleException($e);
   }

  /**
   * This method redirects to home address using CakeResponse Object.
   *
   * @return mixed
   */
   private static function __dismissError()
   {
       return (new CakeResponse)->header(array(
           'Location' => self::$redirectUrl
       ));
   }
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Will try a small layer over the ExceptionRenderer.

Comment: Where exactly in the handler would you call `__dismissError()`?

Comment: @ndm I updated the code block on the question…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a point in using a `CakeResponse` object there... it would work if you'd call `send()` on it, however with only that one header, there's no advantage over using `header()` directly.

That being said, you are however in any case ditching the `Controller.shutdown` and `Dispatcher.afterDispatch` events. They are being dispatched in `ExceptionRenderer::_shutdown()`, and are often used to set response headers (CORS related headers are a good example), so you should figure whether its OK to drop them, or maybe even required.

If you need to keep the `shutdown` and `afterDispatch` events, then you should either fire them on your own, or maybe even use an extended `ExceptionRenderer` that handles that specific type of exception and sends an empty reponse with your location header added.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Development > Exceptions > Using a custom renderer with Exception.renderer to handle application exceptions](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#using-a-custom-renderer-with-exception-renderer-to-handle-application-exceptions)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right, I'll just do another layer for the Renderer.

Will update you if it worked!